# Is there any way to create a package and host my own custom files which contains html, css and js?

Tags: angular, npm, gulp, bower, package

I have a folder which contains an angular2 version of the code which is a combination of HTML, CSS and js files. I want to use this folder in multiple web applications ( which are implemented in Java, dot net & Nodejs). So for easy upgrades and version maintenance, I want to host this folder and want to use this by version wide. is there any way or system to achieve this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Are all your applications hosted on the same server or at least within the same network?

If so, you could just setup a network drive that is accessible to all your apps. You would simply have to reference the files within your projects.

Even if they're on separate networks, you could setup a public file server and simply only allow connections from the IP(s) of your server(s).

If your code is all backend related, you could host it as its own app and connect to it within your other apps, sort of using it like a middleware.

Comment: Package needs to used by unknown applications, so I need a system like Nuget, ... Some thing like that